# Rotate a string in c++?

Tags: c++, string

I'm looking for a way to rotate a string in c++. I spend all of my time in python, so my c++ is *very* rusty.

Here is what I want it to do: if I have a string 'abcde' I want it changed to 'bcdea' (first character moved to the end).
Here is how I did it in python:

```
def rotate(s):
    return s[1:] + s[:1]
```

I'm not sure how to do it in cpp. Maybe use an array of chars?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I recommend [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate):

```
std::rotate(s.begin(), s.begin() + 1, s.end());
```

Comment: section 25.2.10 in the C++ Standard specifies std::rotate

Comment: By the way, if you need a right rotate, use reverse iterators: std::rotate(s.rbegin(), s.rbegin() + 1, s.rend()); and the String becomes "eabcd"

Comment: also an FYI `std::rotate` can be significantly faster than a roll your own implementation. so if you want to ensure both correctness and performance then it is also good to use `std::rotate`. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160875/why-is-stdrotate-so-fast

Answer (score 11):

Here's a solution that "floats" the first character to the end of the string, kind of like a single iteration of bubble sort.

```
#include <algorithm>

string rotate(string s) {
  for (int i = 1; i < s.size(); i++)
    swap(s[i-1], s[i]);
  return s;
}
```

if you want the function to rotate the string in-place:

```
#include <algorithm>

void rotate(string &s) {
  for (int i = 1; i < s.size(); i++)
    swap(s[i-1], s[i]);
}
```

Comment: Be careful of one thing: if s.size() == 0, then s.size()-1 will become 4294...... since s.size() is unsigned.

Answer (score 6):

There is a standard [rotate](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/algorithm/rotate) function found in the algorithm header.
If you want to do this yourself, you could try the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string rotate_string( std::string s ) {
    if (s.empty()) return s;

    char first = s[0];

    s.assign(s, 1, s.size() - 1);
    s.append(1, first);

    return s;
}

int main() {
    std::string foo("abcde");

    std::cout << foo << "\t" << rotate_string(foo) <<  std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But of course, using the standard library is preferable here, and in most cases.

**EDIT #1** I just saw litb's answer. Beat again!
**EDIT #2** I just want to mention that the rotate_string function fails on strings of 0 length. You will get a std::out_of_range error. You can remedy this with a simple try/catch block, or use std::rotate :-)
**EDIT #3** Return the same string if the length of the string is 0.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a relatively simple way:

```
void RotateStringInPlace(char buffer[])
{
    // Get the length of the string.

    int len  = strlen(buffer);
    if (len == 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Save the first character, it's going to be overwritten.

    char tmp = buffer[0];

    //  Slide the rest of the string over by one position.

    memmove(&buffer[0], &buffer[1], len - 1);

    // Put the character we saved from the front of the string in place.

    buffer[len - 1] = tmp;
    return;
}
```

Note that this will modify the buffer in place.

Comment: I would say this is more C than C++, isn't it?

Comment: +1 for using memmove instead of memcpy (which is not safe when the strings may overlap).

Comment: I suppose you could say this is more C than C++, but it's still valid C++, and it's probably more efficient than std::rotate, which is O(n) in the number of characters in the string, while this approach is probably more like O(m) where m is n/(size of a word on your platform).

Comment: @Eric Melski: Your "O(m)" is the same thing as O(n), just faster. Big O notation only measures how well the algorithm scales, not how fast the implementation is.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want these in-place solutions, then your python code can be directly translated to C++, with a bit of extra code to deal with the fact that index out of bounds is bad news in C++.

```
s[1:] --> s.substr(1);
s[:1] --> s[0]; // s[0] is a char not a string, but that's good enough
```

So,

```
std::string rotate(const std::string &s) {
    if (s.size() > 0) return s.substr(1) + s[0];
    return s;
}
```

This isn't the most efficient: it will almost certainly do more string creation than the minimum possible. But you don't usually need the most efficient, and you have `reserve` and `append` if you want to do concatenation without unnecessary allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Is doing it in place a requirement?

If not, you're probably best off taking a substring of all but the first char, and then appending the first char to the end.

Answer (score 1):

At some point i was obsessed with divide and conquer, and used the following

since it 'Divides' the problem to smaller problems my guess is that this performs better.
Expert comments on complexity and memory access behavior are welcome :).

```
Initial Call:
rotate_about(rots_g, 0, i, j - 2);


void rotate_about(char *str, int start, int pivot, int end)
{
    if(pivot == start)
    {
        return ;
    }
    else if((pivot - start) <= (end - pivot))
    {
        int move_bytes = pivot-start;
        swap_bytes(&str[start], &str[pivot],move_bytes);
        rotate_about(str,pivot,pivot+move_bytes,end);
    }
    else
    {
        int move_bytes = end - pivot + 1;
        swap_bytes(&str[start], &str[pivot],move_bytes);
        rotate_about(str, start+move_bytes ,pivot,end);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code in C that does not use any external functions:
It rotates the string in-place both forward and backwards by any value no matter how big.

```
int stringRotate(int value)
  {
  unsigned long   I,J,K;
  unsigned long   index0;
  unsigned long   temp1,temp2;
  unsigned long   length;

  length = stringLength;

  if (value < 0)
    value = length - ((0 - value) % length);

  if (value > length)
    value = value % length;

  J = 0;
  index0 = J;
  temp1 = stringData[J];

  for (I = 0;I < length;I++)
    {
    K = (J + value) % length;
    temp2 = stringData[K];
    stringData[K] = temp1;

    J = K;

    temp1 = temp2;

    if (J == index0)
      {
      J++;
      index0 = J;
      temp1 = stringData[J];
      }
    }

  return 1;
  }
```

To rotate the string both forward and backwards would be a bit tedious so it is better to only do forward rotate and calculate the correct value for backwards.Also if the rotation value is more than the length of the string, then we can just clip it since the result would be the same anyway.

value = length - ((0 - value) % length) : means if the rotation value is negative, then set the value to the length of the string, minus the positive result of the remainder of dividing the value by the length of the string. For example: rotating a string of length 10 by -9 positions would be the same as rotating by +1. Rotating the same string by -19 positions would also be the same as rotating by plus one.
value = value % length : means if the positive value is more than the string length, then divide by the string length and take the remainder. The result would be the same as if we just did it the long way.

To do the rotation in place, we are going to need to jump by the value of of the rotation to swap characters that are that far apart. We start at position zero, move forward by the rotation value and continue jumping by that amount. if we go past the end of the string, we simply wrap back to the beginning. The problem is that if the value is an even number, we will end up right where we started and will miss all the odd characters. The variable index0 is there to indicate where we started from. If we end up back at this index then we need to move forward by one index position and continue jumping. We continue to do this until all the characters are swapped 
At this point we need two temporary variables to do the swapping in place. J is the starting position. We move the character at index J to the first temporary variable. Now we loop I to the length of the string. K is the destination index, J plus the rotation value Wrapped around the end if needed. Move the character at index K to the second temporary variable. Put the character from index J into index K using the first temporary variable. By the way the reason why we do not just move the character directly from index J into index K is because of the last part of the loop, the indices may change in between loops but the characters in temp1 should not. 
Now we exchange the temp1 with temp2. 
This last part is for where the value is an even number and we are back where we started. This will happen by times the rotation value minus one. increment index J by one and reset the starting values. Loop until done.

A video demonstration can be found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TMzaO2WzR24

Answer (score 1):

this code worked for me:

```
using namespace std;

string StrRotate(string &s, int nLeft)
{
     int size = s.size();

     nLeft %= size;

     if(nLeft == 0) return s;

     string after = s.substr(0, nLeft);
     string before = s.substr(nLeft, size - nLeft);

     return before + after;
}
```

Comment: In my tests I found I could calculate before using simply `before = s.substr(nLeft)` because we just want to go all the way to the end of the string.