# Rotating a string using C++

Tags: c++, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rotate a string in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789426/rotate-a-string-in-c)
>   [How to rotate a std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674473/how-to-rotate-a-stdstring)

I am making a application in c++ that works with Command line input. I am entering a string in to the command line

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        if(argc != 2)
        {
             cerr << "Invalid number of CMD arguments" << endl;
             return 1;
        }

        string StringValue = argv[1];
        cout << StringValue << endl;
     }
```

This work's fine. Now i want to loop the character in the string.
 Example: if i enter the word "STATES".

```
    ^STATES|
    |^STATES
    S|^STATE
    ES|^STAT
    TES|^STA
    ATES|^ST
    TETES|^S
    STATES|^
```

Where "^" was the start and "|" the end. how do i do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789426/rotate-a-string-in-c   In-place solution

Comment: The post linked to above by Viktor Latypov is an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `std::rotate` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/

```
string foo = "abcdefg";
std::rotate(foo.begin(), foo.begin() + 3, foo.end());
cout << foo << endl; //prints defgabc
```

Comment: And if i want to do it without the rotate function?

Comment: @user1554408: write you own ). But why not use standard function created for that purpose ?

Comment: Is it possible to loop in the whole string and change the value of a character in the string?

Comment: @user1554408: yes, it's possible: `foo[2] = 'A';`

Comment: @user1554408 it is possible to do that, but there is little point to re-implement `std::rotate` unless this is an exercise or homework.

Comment: No it woks fine thanks. I used it and it rotates it but it does not display after every rotation why is that?

Comment: @user1554408: write a loop: 1) rotate 2) print. And don't forget to accept the answer )

Comment: Thank for the help Andrew it is in perfect running condition.

Comment: @user1554408: please dont't forget to check the answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement on your own...

```
int main() 
{
    string StringValue = "^STATES|";
    string aDoubleStr = StringValue;
    aDoubleStr.append(StringValue);
    for(int i = StringValue.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        string aNewStr = aDoubleStr.substr(i , StringValue.length());
        cout << aNewStr.c_str() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also prefer Andrew's solution using `std::rotate()`. 
But since the OP asked for other solutions in a comment, I would like to "troll" some other ideas here. This one is not very efficient:

```
std::string value = "^STATES|";
size_t pos = 3;
value = value.substr(pos) + value.substr(0, pos);
```

The [other idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678707/how-to-rotate-the-given-string-to-left-or-right-in-c) goes back to Doug McIlroy, Brian Kernighan and P.J. Plauger 8see Jon Bentley: Programming Pearls, chapter 2).
Hold your hands side by side, thumbs in the same direction. 
(It may be easier to have one hand above the other with palms to your body.) 
Turn each hand, then turn both hands connected:

```
_|||| _||||   =>  ||||_ ||||_   =>  _|||| _|||| 
 \L /  \ R/       \L /  \ R/         \R /  \ L/
```

In C++:

```
std::string::iterator mid = value.begin() + pos;
std::reverse(value.begin(), mid);
std::reverse(mid, value.end());
std::reverse(value.begin(), value.end());
```