# Why is std::rotate so fast?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, stl

Why is `std::rotate` so much faster than the equivalent function that cplusplus.com describes?

cplusplus.com's implementation:

```
template <class ForwardIterator>
  void rotate (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator middle, ForwardIterator last)
{
  ForwardIterator next= middle;

  while (first != next)
  {
    swap (*first++, *next++);

    if(next == last)
        next= middle;
    else if (first==middle)
        middle= next;
  }
}
```

I have two insertion sorting algorithms which are entirely identical, with the exception that one uses `std::rotate`, and one uses cplusplus.com's equivalent function. I'm setting them to sort 1000 vectors with 1000 `int` elements. The sort which uses `std::rotate` takes 0.376 seconds, and the other takes 8.181 seconds.

Why is this? I'm not intending to try and make something better than the STL functions but I'm still curious.

Comment: Many possible reasons: `std::rotate` is implemented using architecture-specific assembly, or maybe you're just not compiling using optimization flags

Comment: It could depend a lot on your Standard Library implementation. Have you looked at the source for `std::rotate`?

Comment: What compiler do you use, and what optimization level?

Comment: Just look at the implementation of your compiler - g++ has a lot ofdistinctions to select an algorithm

Comment: Make a custom `std::swap` implementation and record how many times it's called.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Edit:

Since the context is not given, it is not clear if your code calls `std::swap()` or another `swap(a,b)` algorithm like

```
T tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp;
```

When `a` and `b` are vectors of 1000 `int`s each, this would copy all vector elements 3 times. The specialized version of `std::swap()` for containers like `std::vector<T>` call the container `a.swap(b)` method instead, essentially swapping only the dynamic data pointers of the containers.

Also, for different iterator types the `std::rotate()` implementation can utilize some optimizations (see my older, possibly misleading answer below).

---

Caveat: The implementation of `std::rotate()` is implementation-dependent. 
For different iterator categories, different algorithms can be utilized
(e.g. look for `__rotate(` in `bits/stl_algo.h` header of GNU g++).

To shift `n` elements by `m=std::distance(first,middle)` a simple (naive) algorithm like m rotations by one element needs **O(n*m)** moving or copying operations. But only **O(n)** moves are needed, when each element is directly placed to its right position, which results in a (roughly) **m** times faster algorithm.

An example for illustration: Rotate a string `s = "abcdefg"` by three elements:

```
abcdefg : store 'a' in temporary place
dbcdefg : move s[3] to s[0] (where it belongs in the end, directly)
dbcgefg : move s[6] to s[3]
dbcgefc : move s[9%7] to s[6] (wrapping index modulo container size: 9%7 == 2)
dbfgefc : move s[5] to s[2]
dbfgebc : move s[1] to s[5] (another wrapping around)
defgebc : move s[4] to s[1]
defgabc : move 'a' from temporary place to s[4]
```

For `n` and `m` with greatest common divisor 1 you are done now. Otherwise you have to repeat that scheme `n/m` time for the first `m` consecutive elements (`n > m` assumed here).
This little more complicated algorithm is much faster.

For **bidirectional iterators** another legendary O(3n) algorithm can be used, referred to as "flipping hands". According to Jon Bentley's book [Programming Pearls](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8177588583) it was used in early UNIX editors for moving text:

Place your hands in front of you, one above the other, thumbs up. Now

1. Turn one hand.
2. Turn the other.
3. Turn both, connected to each other.

In code:

```
reverse(first, middle);
reverse(middle, last);
reverse(first, last);
```

For **random access iterators** large chunks of memory can be relocated by `swap_ranges()` (or `memmove()` operations for POD types).

Microoptimization by utilising assembler operations can give a small extra amount of acceleration, it can be done on top of the fasted algorithm.

Algorithms using consecutive elements instead of "hopping around" in memory also result in smaller number of cache misses on modern computer architectures.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll need to do a lot of reading on iterators, algorithms and the STL before I can truly understand all of the factors at play here. I'll look into alternative algorithms when I get the chance =)

Comment: The algorithm OP quoted performs O(n) moves, not O(nm).

Answer (score 35):

As the commentors already stated, it depends on  your Standard Library implementation. But the code that you posted is valid even for **forward iterators**. As such, it imposes very little requirements (only that these iterators can be incremented and dereferenced).

Stepanov's classic [**Elements of Programming**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032163537X) devotes an entire chapter (10) to `rotate` and other rearrangement algorithms. For forward iterators, the series of swaps in your code gives `O(3N)` assignments. For **bidirectional iterators**, three consecutive calls to `reverse` yield another `O(3N)` algorithm. For **random access iterators**, `std::rotate` can be implemented as `O(N)` assignments by defining a **permutation of indices** w.r.t. to the starting iterator `first`.

All the above algorithms are in-place. Using a memory buffer, it is possible that the random access version can benefit from the greater cache locality of `memcpy()` or `memmove()` (if the underlying value type is POD) in which entire blocks of contiguous memory can be swapped. If your insertion sort is done on an array or `std::vector`, it is likely that your Standard Library will take advantage of this optimization.

**TL;DR**: trust your Standard Library and don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: > For random access iterators, std::rotate is very likely to benefit from memmove() optimizations in which entire blocks of contiguous memory can be swapped.

This is, in general, not true. If the underlying data type is a POD (plain old data) type, then memmove/memcpy can be used. Otherwise the copy/move constructors for the objects _must_ be called.

Comment: Thanks. These comments and answers have given me a good deal of insight. Looks like I have a lot of learning to do before I can fully understand what's going on...

Comment: @bradshire The fact that you want to learn and understand is the important part. Now comes the never-ending effort!

Comment: In Big O notation O(3N) is the same as O(N) since we are only interested in the function behavior.